# Writing multiple .txt in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling with a simple thing since couple days. I'm trying to write 50 .txt files with a "Hello World" inside. Unfortunately all my loops create just one text file. May someone give me some hints?

I found this loop in another topic but I get an error anyway:

```
for(i in 1:50) 
{ 
writeLines("Hello World", path = sprintf("file%s.txt", i))
}
```

Comment: It's not `path = etc`, it's `con = etc`. I'm voting to close as off-topic, a simple typo. When you get errors like that one, `unused argument (path = sprintf("file%s.txt", i))`, try `help("function name")`, in this case `help("writeLines")`.

Comment: Dear lord, you're right. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
for(i in 1:50) { 

  # 1. File name
  fname <- sprintf("file_%s.txt", i)

  # 2. Create file connection
  fileConn <- file(fname)

  # 3. Write data
  writeLines("Hello World", fileConn)

  # 4. Close connection
  close(fileConn)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sink`

```
for(i in 1:50) {

  sink(paste(i, "outfile.txt"))
  cat("Hello World")
  sink()

}
```

Or just use `cat`:

```
for(i in 1:50) {

  cat("Hello World",file=paste(i, "outfile.txt"), sep="\n")

}
```